# Implementing efficient arithmetic operators

Tags: c++

I am implementing a `expr` class that is not cheap to copy and I want to implement proper "efficient" arithmetic operators. For the sake of this question, I'll focus on `operator-`.

```
class expr {
public:
    expr(expr const&) = default;
    expr(expr &&) = default;

    expr operator-() const& { return -expr(*this); }
    expr operator-() && { 
        // Perform operations in-place.
        return std::move(*this);
    }

    expr& operator-=(expr const& other) & {
        // In-place operations.
        return *this;
    }

    expr&& operator-=(expr const& other) && {
        // In-place operations.
        return std::move(*this); // Do I really need this move?
    }
};

expr operator-(expr const& lhs, expr const& rhs) {
    return expr(lhs) -= rhs;
}

expr operator-(expr &&lhs, expr &&rhs) {
    return std::move(lhs -= rhs);  // (A)
}
```

Here are a few questions that are kind of related:

1. Is it the proper way to implement `operator-()`? Is there are more idiomatic-way of doing so?
2. In `(A)`, do I need the `std::move`? I think so because `lhs -= rhs` returns a `expr&`, but I am not really sure. I think `std::move(lhs) -= rhs` would work but...
3. Should I implement `expr&& operator-=(expr const&) &&` if it performs the same operations as the `&`-qualified version? What would happen in the following code with or without this overload:

```
expr e1;

// Is e2 copy-constructed or move-constructed if there is no operator-=() &&? And if there is?
auto e2 = expr() -= e1;
```

Comment: I just recently read somewhere that `std::move()` in `return` is almost always wrong. [Move Semantics and Compiler Optimizations](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_06.html)

Comment: The two operator "-=" definitions in your code differ only in return type. Such operators/functions cannot be overloaded

Comment: @JPX Not really actually, they also differ in the reference qualification of the object (& vs. &&).

Comment: @Holt expr& and expr&& are two different types which are also the return types in your two functions - so you cannot overload by different return types only.

Comment: @JPX - Nothing is overloaded by the return type only. The member functions are **ref-qualified**, `const &` and `&&` respectively.

Comment: @JPX sorry, the first function should have been &- qualified only, I’ve edited the question.

Comment: Can you define "efficient"? Efficient in code written: write the assign-arithmetic operators (+=, -=, *=, /=) and reuse those for the "normal" arithmetic operators. Efficient in performance, copy and move: write all operators with carefully selected use of move. Which one do you mean?

Comment: @André Efficient in avoiding copy whenever possible.

Comment: @Holt I would like to argue (hence not an answer) that this easily "explodes" combinatorily the moment you need to deal with conversions to other classes as well. In such a case, you may need to deal with all possible overloads and write copy-efficient code for all of them. This becomes a huge burden and is in my opinion not worth the speed gain. Obvious question: have you measured the performance and are you really sure? ;-)

Comment: @André Well, I would counter-argue (if that's a word) that I don't really care about conversion to other classes. The number of overloads will obviously be greater than with standard operators, but not that much - AFAIK, you simply need the rvalue overload for the member operators (so x2) and a few overloads for the binary ones (something like x4). These operations will be called millions if not billions of times repeatedly, and are the core, hence the bottleneck of the application, so I've accepted the fact that I need a few overloads to speed things up.

Comment: Which standard do you target? C++17 has copy elision guaranty

Comment: @Jarod42 I can target C++17 but I don't think guaranteed copy elision (as defined in the C++17 standard) will help for the two above cases. For instance for the rvalue-overload of `operator-`, guaranteed elision does not change anything I think. But I might be wrong.

Comment: One part of the question is returning `expr` or `expr&&` (you take one for unary operator-, and the other for `-=`). By value might incur extra move without elision, and by reference forbid such elision but might avoid some move constructors (lifetime extension might also be an issue). So is your class cheap to move or not?

Comment: @Jarod42 You can assume that the class is cheap to move. My code is actually inconsistent (I wrote `operator-=() &&` after), and it could probably return a simple `expr` in this case, although I'm not sure this is "idiomatic" C++ (i.e. `operator +=` returning by value) but since I've never seen example with `&&`-overload for `operator+=`, I don't really know... Also, I think I would still need the `move` in these cases, otherwise, I would get a copy of `*this` instead of a `move`?

Comment: Purely semantically I’m not sure a modifying overload makes sense for rvalue references, which are after all unnamed temporaries. I can’t think of any scenario anyway — and you’d probably want to *forbid* accidental code that does something like `expr{…} -= …`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Well, you might be right... I actually added this overload while writing this question. But I more concerned about the other stuff actually (`&&`-overload for the unary-operator and the binary operators).

Comment: No time to write a proper answer now but here’s a Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/j4TEo8 — tl;dr: generally `std::move` inhibits NRVO, but of course that only works if the value is actually eligible for NRVO, i.e. it has to be a locally defined value. Rvalue parameters don’t qualify, so we need `std::move` in the `return` to prevent copying.